# Particle System, want to emit a particle AND a lamp

Tags: animation, particles

I have made a mesh of a submarine. I have parented it with a lamp, like a headlight on a car. I have made a particle system to created BOIDs of these submarines, as if they were swarming around. Only the submarine mesh gets rendered in the system. Does anyone know a way of making the lamps appear with the mesh in the particle system too?

Any help would be massively appreciated! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

After a short experiment I have been able to get a lamp to appear as part of a particle by using the Group option in the Render section and activate the Whole Group checkbox.  Since the mesh and lamp are both part of the group I created they are both instantiated for every particle.

Probably the biggest gotcha is to set the Size property underneath the Whole Group checkbox to something reasonable (it defaults to rather tiny).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could create a mesh light instead of a lamp and join it to the submarine mesh. Just another option.